# Decrease the volume of vector tiles generated by GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, mapbox, vector-tiles

I've used GeoServer [vector tile extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/install.html) to produce PBF files from set of shape files. The problem is the generated MVTs from GeoServer have larger volume in comparison with Mapbox ones. How can I reduce the volume of each PBF file to be optimized?

Comment: Do both have the same attributes? Is the number of features the same in both sets? If there there is no difference in those two aspects then probably tiles from GeoServer have more vertices in geometries and simplification could help.

Comment: Thanks @user30184, there is a question related to your comment. Does the number of vertices have bigger effect on the volume of a vector tile or attributes of features?

Comment: Hard to say by looking only at the specification https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/. Each extra vertex adds one LineTo and each attribute what it happens to contain but I have no idea about how effectively those two gets compressed when they are converted into protobuf format.